# Is there any way to optimize the time taken for generating the code coverage report in VSTS?

Tags: typescript, testing, azure-devops, mocha.js, code-coverage

Why does it take long time (>1 min) to get the code coverage report on running the related command in VSTS? What are the ways to optimize this process?

Comment: Hi Sree Divya, just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry we do not have any way to achieve this.

As a workaround, you can set a variable `disable.coverage.autogenerate` in your pipeline to **true**.

[image]

This will give you a link to download the coverage.xml which was uploaded. This was the old experience before HTML generator.

It could reduce some time used for auto generated code coverage report details in Code Coverage tab of pipeline.